# Python Selenium impossible, tried id, class can't find XPath

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enter a field with text (email), in the username box. However, it is not interacting with it. I have it in a `try` & `except` statement but it only spits out excepts.

Website is [account.protonmail.com/signup](https://account.protonmail.com/signup)

I have tried everything: `xpath`, `class`, `id`, but nothing works. I am losing my mind!
Password works fine:

Does not work:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(password)
```

Does work:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="repeat-password"]').send_keys(password)
```

And yes, I do wait until JavaScript finishes running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is in `iframe`, and needs `explicit waits` :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://account.protonmail.com/signup")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[sandbox^='allow-scripts']")))
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#username"))).send_keys('someemail@gmail.com')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank  you. Marked as correct answer. Do you know how to switch back to normal mode outside of iframe? The password ones fail now

Comment: driver.switch_to.default_content()

Answer (score 0):

Element you are trying to access is inside an iframe. First you need to switch to the frame like this

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'account-api.protonmail.com')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult for you to write everything, make it easier

```
click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').click()
click.send_keys('')
click.send_keys(password)
```

Comment: Add some explanation